# Problems compiling opensips via menuconfig/

Tags: opensips

I'm beating my head against the wall here. I've tried this on several different boxes and keep getting the same results...

after trying to compile opensips on Debian 8, I'm getting the following make error:
Generating parser
Generating lexer
make: Nothing to be done for 'menuconfig/'.

I'm fairly certain I have the correct dependencies install and am following the documatation to a tee, any advice would be welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to hit the `Tab` key, thus actually typing `make menuconfig`, rather than `make menuconfig/`, which the build system currently does not know how to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the response here! Don't even remember asking this question but wanted to thank you.